# How to get the shipping settings

Tags: woocommerce, settings

I do not get the shipping settings. Used:

```
echo get_option( 'woocommerce_flat_rate_enabled' );
```

But it returns `Null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the settings via;

`$settings = get_option( 'woocommerce_flat_rate_settings' );`

which will give you back an array of values.

```
array (
  'enabled' => 'yes',
  'title' => 'Flat Rate',
  'availability' => 'all',
  'countries' => '',
  'tax_status' => 'taxable',
  'cost_per_order' => '',
  'additional_costs' => '',
  'type' => 'order',
  'additional_costs_table' => false,
  'minimum_fee' => '',
  'addons' => '',
  'options' => '',
  'cost' => '',
  'fee' => '',
)
```

The same goes for other shipping methods;

```
$settings = get_option( 'woocommerce_free_shipping_settings
woocommerce_local_delivery_settings
woocommerce_international_delivery_settings
```